# Function is not repeating all if statement

Tags: javascript

Hi I have a Problem my code is just executing ones but the loop works if i want to console log i
the only thing whats is logged normaly to the console is:
377 2 2021

(here is the code):

```js
let time = (Math.floor(target / aDM));
let tDay = currentDate[0] + time
let tMonth = currentDate[1]
let tYear = currentDate[2]
targetDate()

function targetDate() {
  let i = 0
  while (i < 100) {
    if (tMonth % 2 === 1 && tMonth && tDay > 30) {
      tMonth++;
      tDay = (tDay - 30);
    }
    if (tYear % 2 === 0 && tMonth != 2 && tDay > 30) {
      tMonth++;
      tDay = (tDay - 30);
    }

    if (tMonth % 2 === 1 && tMonth != 2 && tDay > 31) {
      tMonth++;
      tDay = (tDay - 31)
    }
    if (tMonth > 28) {
      tDay++;
      tDay = (tDay - 31)
    }
    if (tMonth > 12) {
      tMonth = (tMonth - 12)
      tYear++
    }
    i++;
  }
  console.log(tDay, tMonth, tYear)
}
```

Comment: You should use `else if`. Otherwise, each `if` statement will use the updated `tMonth` from the previous one.

Comment: Where do you set `target` and `currentDate`.

Comment: For purposes of clarifying the question, it might help to specify the function's inputs as constants, and say what result you were expecting.

Comment: @Barmar currentDate and Target were set way back in the code but these ones are not causing the problem

Comment: @BipedPhill  I dont think that changing them to constant will solve the problem. The function would try to do an Assignment to an constan variable.

currentDate = [10, 01, 2021]
Time= 397
expectedOutput = 15. 2. 2022

Answer (score 1):

you have several problems with this code.

1. Not good practice to use global variables. you should pass your variables into the function.
2. You probably want "else"s in your code. otherwise its possible for the code to execute several of those conditions at once for the same iteration of i.
3. Your logic: (tMonth % 2 === 1) is flawed because if you start with tMonth % 2 == 0, there's no way for it to get to 1
4. All of this logic seems overly complicated and likely to fail. Far simpler to use standard date functions if you are simply trying to step through days of a year.
5. What about leap years?
6. Months do not simply alternate from 30 to 31 and back. in fact right in the middle of the year (July & august) you have back to back 31 day months.

Comment: I suspect the first condition was intended to address problem 6, but they left out that part. `&& tMonth` presumably should be `&& tMonth > 7`